# Where can I find information on the Troika?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, europe

I am particularly interested in information on the Troika which may be useful to a UK politician (they are running on a platform that's explicitly anti-Troika, but I want them to present them with balanced information nonetheless).

A quick Google search just turns up a bunch of links to third-party articles and resources basically saying: 'Troika is bad because... umkay'.

That's not particularly helpful. What I want is to be able to say to this politician: 'ok, this action was taken in this resolution which means/caused this/these other things' or 'this money was spent here, which seems to have caused x, y and z'.

Can anyone tell me how to find the details of resolutions, institutional frameworks and financials of this publicly elected (sort of) institution, so I can present with something concrete when I report to them in a couple of weeks?

Also, any suggestions or tips for parsing the data would be welcome.

Comment: This troika? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_troika

Comment: @AndrewGrimm That's the one (and also three, if you'll pardon the accidental religious implication... ;))

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. I think to answer the question properly one would need to analyse the processes internal structure and policies of the three parts. If the question were focussed on a particular action of the Troika, it could be answered, but as it stands it seems to cover all actions (past and potential) and so is too broad.

Answer (score -1):

Saying that the Troika is publically elected is similar to saying that the Chinese goverment is publically elected. It's true for certain values of "publically elected" but not what most people mean with the term.

The Troika consists of three organisations European Commission (EC), the European Central Bank (ECB) and the International Monetary Fund (IMF).

If you want to understand it you have to understand those three organisations. The European Central Bank for example is designed to be independent from democratic decision makers to the extend that it sued other EU organs when they wanted to make sure that the European Central Bank doesn't engage in corruption.

It's makeup is also pretty complex given that it's bord is made up of the head of the Central Banks of the member states which work differently.

To actually understand the setup you have to read a lot of documents. All those institutions have homepages that tell you how about their internal structure.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are not answering the question. The question explicitly asked **Where can I find information on the Troika?**. All you wrote which directly addresses this question is "read a lot of documents" (but not which documents and where to find them) and "look on their websites" without even having the courtesy to link to them.

Comment: @Philipp It's a useful starting point in the sense that there may be information concerning overall structure on the websites, though with the wealth of information there I'm only moderately hopeful about finding anything useful in the week or two I have left. Still, it is important to know where to focus efforts, and knowing that these website actually *have* the information I'm looking for will allow me to concentrate on information gathering in these places, without having to worry that such efforts might be in vane. Unfortunately these things always end up being about balancing priorities.